# Card game based on dropping 3 of a kind or minimum of a 3 card straight flush

Tags: identify-this-game

I am looking for the name of this game with a regular 52 card deck.

Each player (minimum 2) is dealt 9 cards. Before the game starts each player selects one card to "discard" and the discards are traded between players (e.g. if there is two players, player A gets player B's discard and player B gets player A's discard ). The player doesn't know the identity of the other players discard until the trade is made.

The game then begins by the first player placing the top card of the remainder of the deck face up next to the face down deck. Players take turns doing so until either someone wins or there are no cards left.

The point of the game is to get rid of all 9 cards by dropping cards in groups of a minimum of 3 cards into a drop area (per player) and the drop area must have 10 cards to win.

A game can end with no winner.

The dropped groups can either be:

- 3 of a kind
- straight flush of a minimum of 3 cards.

If either player can use the last face up card to complete a group they can pick it up, drop the group, and must then drop an additional card face up onto the face up pile. Players can continue to add to groups in their drop area (e.g. if a player had dropped an A3, A4, A5 and the last card drawn was an A2, they can add it to the group and drop a card from their hand).

Also, groups can be re-arranged to create/complete new groups (e.g. player had dropped A3, A4, A5, A6. Player has a Q6 in their hand and last face up card is a 6D, they can pick up the 6D, take the A6 (preserving the group of 3 minumum straight flush) and combine with the Q6 to drop a 3 of a kind).

Regarding the needing 10 cards in the drop group to win, once all 9 original cards have been dropped the player waits until they can pick up a face up card that completes any dropped group to win.

There may be some other special cases that I can't think of at the moment but this is the gist of the game.

Any idea what the name is?

Comment: Sounds like some variation of [Rummy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rummy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to play this game with my grandma, we called it "combinations", but I am not sure about the real name.

Rummy have tons of variations, maybe you can find it here:
https://www.rummypassion.com/rummy-wiki/rummy-game